# 0 or not any character match in Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to mach a string with 10 digits or 9 digits.

It must match the following: *0123456789 or 123456789*

I tried with this expression `^[0|\e]\d{9}$`, but it is not working

Comment: I tried this expression ^[0|\e]\d{9}$ but this is not working

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: What's the leading zero for? Are you looking for leading zeroes specifically? Maybe `0?[0-9]{9}`? Or `0?[1-9][0-9]{8}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this one:

```
^0?\d{9}$
```

This assumes 012345678 would fulfill your criteria as well; namely you can have 10 digits only if it starts with a 0, but any combination of nine digits is ok.

Answer (score -1):

This simple regular expression should work-

`@"^0?[0-9]{9}$""`

Example:

```
var match = Regex.Match(Your_string, @"^0?[0-9]{9}$");
if (match.Success)
Console.WriteLine("Sucess");
```

Comment: he wants the ten digit mode only when it starts with zero.

Comment: This won't work, the OP's intent was that 10-digit numbers must start with a zero.  He wasn't explicit if there were additional restrictions though.

Comment: Well I dint get the question right. Made the change.